# Problem with understanding the expected value $E(y_t)$ in definition of a stationary time series.

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

I am trying to understand the conditions for time series $\{y_t\}$ to be stationary, i.e.:

- $E(y_t)=\mu$ is constant for all $t >0,$
- $Var(y_t) = V$ is constant for all $t >0$ and
- $cov(y_t, y_s)$ depends only on $|t-s|$ and not $t$ itself.

I came across a [youtube video by ritvikmath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY-j2Wof51c&ab_channel=ritvikmath) explaining this concept and it shows this example:

[image]

In 3:00 he says that the mean of plotted series is **constant** and I don't understand it completely.

If there were multiple time series, expected value of each variable $Y_t$ could be estimated as mean of $y_t$s. But how is it done if there is only one series? For each variable $Y_t$ we have only one datapoint, I don't understand how it's possible to know $E(y_t)$ here. Same for variance.